# Access Javascript variable in php in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jsonp

Hi I am facing problem with json data. Here is my js code.

```
   <script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
         url:"http://example.com/salary?from=USD&to=GBP",
         dataType: 'jsonp', 
         success:function(json){         
             alert(json['to']);
         },
         error:function(){
             alert("Error");
         },
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to use json data in PHP in same page.
I know that you cannot assign Javascript value to PHP variable.

Is there way to do this?

Or is possible to do similar task in php (Jquery Ajax cross domain) like above javascript code ?

Any help?

Comment: "Or is possible to do similar task in php" > of course it is, it's just an HTTP request and response. The response is formatted as JSON but is plain text. And JSON can be parsed in PHP. Some googling will find you all the resources you need to go forward.

Comment: I couldnt get your point. can you be more specific with example plz. Do you want to retrieve array from php result in ajax?

Comment: @Bartdude: Can i use file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/..') and after this json_decode() to similar task in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your js code

```
var my_json_obj = new Object();
my_json_obj .name = "Lanny";
my_json_obj .age = "25";
my_json_obj .location = "China";
var json_str = JSON.stringify(my_json_obj);
<script>
    $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "my.php",
                    data: { 
                     postData: json_str 
                    },
                    success: function (data) { alert(data) },
                    eror: function (data) { alert(data) }
                });
    });
</script>
```

your my.php file

```
$postData=$_POST['postData'];
$my_obj=json_decode($postData,true);
$name=$my_obj['name'];
$age=$my_obj['age'];
$localtion=$my_obj['location'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with AJAX.

You need a script, which will give javascript vars to the PHP Script, like:

```
var PHPFile = 'PHPFile.php?arg1=' + arg1 + '&arg2=' + arg2;
```

In the "PHPFile.php" you can access them by

```
$arg1 = $_GET["arg1"];
$arg2 = $_GET["arg2"];
```

Or you could do that with jquery $.ajax-> data, too.

You can access them by

```
$arg1 = $_POST["arg1"];
$arg2 = $_POST["arg2"];
```

Something like that:

```
result = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false, 
    url: 'PHPFile.php',
    data: ({
        arg1: arg1,
        arg2: arg2
    })
}).responseText;

alert(result);
```

EDIT:

If you want to do that with a json-object, try this:

```
json_decode();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php